# Git losing changes

Tags: git

I have 3 files, A, B, C.

I made some changes to A and B and then ran `git diff` to check the changes I made. Everything looked good. Then I made a change to 'C' and ran `git diff` again but this time it shows only the changes I made to 'C'. If I type `git diff HEAD` then I can see the changes to all 3 files.

What's gonna happen when I commit? Will it commit only the changes to C or A, B, C?

Comment: Are you staging these changes at all ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't run `git add` for file A and B before running `git diff` for the second time?

Comment: @Brian, no I just do git add and git diff before git commit. I'll check what 'staging' is.

at-Lorenzo: Yes, I did git add for A and B..and checked git diff. Then changed C and git add C.. then did git diff again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `git add`ed A and B to the index, you can do `git diff --cached` to see their changes. `git diff` only shows unstaged changes. Quoth the [git diff man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-diff):

```
Various ways to check your working tree

    $ git diff            (1)
    $ git diff --cached   (2)
    $ git diff HEAD       (3)

1. Changes in the working tree not yet staged for the next commit.
2. Changes between the index and your last commit; what you would be committing
   if you run "git commit" without "-a" option.
3. Changes in the working tree since your last commit; what you would be
   committing if you run "git commit -a"
```

Ultimately, you should also use `git status` before you commit to see what exactly you'll be committing.

Answer (score 1):

You added A and B via `git add`. If you run `git diff` after staging filex for the next commit, you won't see the changes. This is the expected behaviour, and you can run `git diff --cached` to see the changes to the added files.

If you the modify another file, C, `git diff` will show only the changes in C (unstaged yet).
The command `git diff HEAD` shows the changes for both staged and unstaged files: exactly, it shows the changes in the working tree *since your last commit*.

To answer briefly to your original question, `git commit` will commit the changes to all the files you modified (A, B, C), and not only C.